# Any alternate way to avoid null value return in asp.net server control

Tags: asp.net, properties, null, viewstate, servercontrol

I created a server control and **test.aspx** Code is shown below .

When   dll is loaded , `RenderContents()` function gets called.
   Control transfer to DataSource property ,
   but `ViewState["DataSource"]` returns `null` .

To avoid it , I initialized `ViewState["DataSource"]` using -

```
ViewState["DataSource"] = _Pages_dummy;
```

My Question is -
   if i do not want to use initialization , is there any alternate way  so that `ViewState["DataSource"]`  will not return `null` value "?

=================================== ===============================================

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ServerControl2
{
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:ServerControl1 runat=server></{0}:ServerControl1>")]
    public class ServerControl1 : WebControl
    {
        private string[,] _Pages_dummy= { {"1","2","3","4"} ,  {"11","22","33","44"}};

        public ServerControl1() 
        {
           ViewState["DataSource"] = _Pages_dummy; 
           // if user do not initialize viewstate , we use dummmey array .
        }

        public ServerControl1(string[,] pages)        
        {
            ViewState["DataSource"] = pages;  
           // user must initialize viewstate .
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
         public  string[,]  DataSource
        {
            get
            {
                return (string[,])ViewState["DataSource"];
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["DataSource"] = value;
            }
        }    
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
        {
            get
            {
                return HtmlTextWriterTag.Div;
            }
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.WriteBeginTag("div");

            if (DataSource != null)
            {
                    for (int i = 0; i < DataSource.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                       for (int j = 0; j < DataSource.GetLength(1); j++)
                       {

                       }
                   }
            }    
        } // RenderContents     
    }// class
}// namespace
```

**test.aspx.cs**

```
         ServerControl2.ServerControl1 n1 = new ServerControl2.ServerControl1();                     
          n1.DataSource[0,0] = "hjkhjk";
          n1.DataSource[0,1] = "jkljk";
          n1.DataSource[0,2] = "hjk";
          n1.DataSource[0,3] = "fjgfjhhgj";   
          Response.Write(n1.DataSource[0,0]);
          Response.Write(n1.DataSource[0,1]);
          Response.Write(n1.DataSource[0,2]);
          Response.Write(n1.DataSource[0,3]);
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I'm not really clear on why you want this, but if you want ViewState["DataSource"] to always have a value, you would have to initialize it to *something*. It starts out being empty.

Comment: If you don't put a value in the viewstate variable, and you try to retrieve it, what could you possibly expect to retrieve other than null?

Comment: See inside default contructor . Suppose I comment 
// ViewState["DataSource"] = _Pages_dummy;

What I want is -
ViewState["DataSource"]  should not return null .
Is it possible?

Comment: When   dll is loaded , RenderContents() function gets called internally .  
Hence it is not possible to initialize by calling default constructor . Did You get my point?

Comment: Not possible. It doesn't really make sense. If you never set it to something, it will always be null, unless you do something like in Ceres' answer, where you initialize it in the property definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the viewstate is null in the Datasource property. As long as you use the property instead of Viewstate("Datasource") directly, you should be fine.

```
[Bindable(true)]
[Category("Appearance")]
[DefaultValue("")]
[Localizable(true)]
 public  string[,]  DataSource
{
    get
    {
        string[,] value = (string[,])ViewState["DataSource"];
        if (value == null) {
            return __Pages_dummy

        }
        return value ;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["DataSource"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried 
 string[,] value = (string[,])ViewState["DataSource"];
                if (value == null) {
                    return _Pages_dummy;
                }
                return value ;

It is working fine. 
But how will i come know what should be size of _Pages_dummy. It may differ  in various scenarios . I can not guess _Pages_dummy size .

Comment: string[,] value = (string[,])ViewState["DataSource"];
 if (value == null) {    return null;  }
 return value ;
Now It is working .
Thanks Ceres.